# No AD policy on Win10 after a reset

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10

I got a Windows Server 2016 with many Windows 10 client.
On these clients, if I reset the computer with the "Keep my files" option, everything works as planned (computer is reset, files are still there) but there is no policies implemented on the freshly installed computer after that.

Meaning, the computer is still on the domain and the network config is fine, but the policies are not pushed into the computer anymore. I did try a **gpupdate /force** with no success.

Please advise and thanks!

Comment: `the computer is still on the domain` how are you validating that?

Comment: Both commands in the terminal confirms it : 

**>systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain" . 
Domain:                                    xyz.local**
and 
**>wmic computersystem get domain
Domain
xyz.local**

And my admin password give me admin right on the client computer.

Comment: Are the machines in the correct OU that the policy is being applied to or are the policies being applied to the entire domain? Are the policies properly linked?

Comment: Policies apply to the entire domain. And I assume they are properly linked as I never have any issue of that kind before. With a new Win10 computer, no issue, only when I reset one with the "Keep my files" option. 

Also, I was able to reproduce this issue, by resetting a second computer with the "keep my files" option, and I got the same issue as the first time.

Comment: How are you determining that domain based group policies are not being applied?

Comment: @joeqwerty : I've policies about shared network drives and printer, and nothing is present.

Comment: I'd suggest running gpresult on one of the affected machines and seeing what the result is (no pun intended).

Comment: `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain" . Domain: xyz.local and >wmic computersystem get domain Domain xyz.local` Are you able to browse to `\\domain\sysvol`?

Comment: @GregAskew : Great! It works now! In \\domain\sysvol, I was able to execute script that reloaded my missing policy. Thanks!

Thanks to everybody :)